# How to solve PDFBox's unsupported/disabled operation problems

Tags: java, applet, pdfbox, japplet

I'm using **PDFbox** to render a **PDF with forms** in a **java applet** and when I change the forms information for the first time, it takes way too much time to reflect the new information in the displayed form and PDFBox logs the following two messages:

```
[date] org.apache.pdfbox.util.PDFStreamEngine processOperator
INFO: unsupported/disabled operation: BMC
[date] org.apache.pdfbox.util.PDFStreamEngine processOperator
INFO: unsupported/disabled operation: EMC
```

Consequent form changes are reflected in an accepted time frame and PDF don't log that information anymore.

### Questions:

1. Is the first time slowness directly related to the logged information or is it to be expected?
2. If it's not to be expected, how can one solve this problem?

Comment: It most likely is not connected.  **BMC** and **EMC** delimit marked content. It can be completely ignored for rendering purposes.